# Conditional probability with geometric distribution

Tags: conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, regression, expected-value

$X$ and $Y$ are linearly independent random variables with geometric distribution. They have the same $p$ parameter. How can I calculate the following expressions:

a) $P(X=k|X<Y)$=?

b) $P(X=k|X=Y)$=?

c) $\mathbb{E}(X\mid X+Y)$=?

For b) I got: $(1-p)^{2k}[(1-p)^{-2}+1]$

I made a matrix, and its elements was $P(X=i;Y=j)$ ... I took the sum of the diagonal elements and I divided $P(X=k;Y=k)=p^{2}(1-p)^{2k-2}$ with this sum. Is it a correct solution?

a) was harder...

$P(X=k\mid X<Y)=\frac{P(X=k;X<Y)}{P(X<Y)}$

${P(X<Y)}$ is the sum of the elements in the upper triangle matrix, because this matrix is symmetric. The "probability" of the upper triangle matrix is

$\left(1-(sum\:of\:the\:diagonal\:elements)\right)/2$

$P(X=k|X<Y)$ is $p(1-p)^{k-1}\sum_{j=k+1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{j-1}p=p(1-p)^{k-1}\cdot\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{j-1}p-\sum_{j=1}^{k}(1-p)^{j-1}p\right)$

I divided this result with $P(X<Y)$ (calculated above) and I got the following disgusting expression:

$2\frac{(1-p)^{2k-1}p}{1-\frac{p^{2}}{1-(1-p)^{2}}}$

Is it correct? I'm working on task c) but I would appreciate your help :DD

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing the in double instead of single dollar signs. This is particularly important for readability when you have nested fractions and exponents. You can get the proper font for text like "sum of the diagonal elements" within a mathematical expression using `\text{sum of the diagonal elements}`.

Comment: You introduce $X$ and $Y$ as "linearly independent", which is a term sometimes used to mean that their covariance is $0$. But later you seem to assume that their joint distribution factorizes, which is only the case if $X$ and $Y$ are (stochastically) independent. Perhaps this is what you intended to assume in the first sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a), we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X=k\mid X<Y) &= \frac{\mathbb P(X=k,X<Y)}{\mathbb P(X<Y)}\\
&= \frac{(1-p)^{k-1}p\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty (1-p)^{i-1}p}{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} (1-p)^{i-1}p(1-p)^{j-1}p}\\
&= \frac{p (1-p)^{2 k-1}}{\frac{1-p}{2-p}}\\
&= p(2-p) (1-p)^{2 (k-1)}.
\end{align}

For b), we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X=k\mid X=Y) &= \frac{\mathbb P(X=k,X=Y)}{\mathbb P(X=Y)}\\
&= \frac{(1-p)^{k-1}p(1-p)^{k-1}p}{\sum_{i=1}^\infty (1-p)^ip(1-p)^ip}\\
&= p(2-p) (1-p)^{2 (k-1)}.
\end{align}

For c) we have for each positive integer $n$

\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X\mid X+Y=n] &= \frac{\mathbb E\left[X\mathsf 1_{\{X+Y=n\}}\right]}{\mathbb P(X+Y=n)}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb E\left[X\mathsf 1_{\{X+Y=n\}}\right]}{1 - 2\left(\frac{1-p}{2-p}\right)}.
\end{align}

I am not sure how to evaluate $\mathbb E[X\mathsf 1_{\{X=Y\}}]$, however.